# After login site is not going to right URL

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-users

I used redirect to send the user to the homepage after logging in but when user is trying to login it is taking the user to some different URL.

login function in views.py-

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/homepage')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is not active.")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
            print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

    else:
        return render(request, 'Login.html', {})
```

The URL it is taking to-
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/"

login.html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "_inject.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- <div class="jumbotron"> -->


      <h1 class="c1">Login here</h1>

        <form method="POST" class="form">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% bootstrap_form form %}
          {% buttons %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
          {% endbuttons %}
        </form>

        <!-- </div> -->

      </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

URL patterns-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', views.index, name='base'),
    path('signup/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('createpost/', views.CreatePost, name='createpost'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="login.html"),name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path("by/<username>/<int:pk>/",views.PostDetail.as_view(),name="single"),
    path("delete/<int:pk>/",views.DeletePost.as_view(),name="delete"),
    path('', views.ListPosts.as_view(), name="homepage"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings file, add the following:
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'homepage'`

This will redirect the user to the homepage after successful login.

`LOGIN_URL= 'login'`
`LOGOUT_URL= 'logout'`

For more information, take a look at the following: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url